# 500 ошибка при переходе на другую страницу, Modx

Tags: mysql, modx

При переходе с главной на любую другую страницу сайта появляется сообщение об ошибке 500:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, support@sweb.ru and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.29 (Gentoo) mod_dp/0.99.7 PHP/7.1.26 Server at vmleasing.ru Port 80

В логах modx нашел эту запись, но не могу понять куда "копать" дальше, заранее благодарю за помощь:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY `modResource`.`pagetitle` ASC LIMIT 20' at line 1
)
```

Comment: Ищите запрос, который привёл к ошибке, и показывайте полный его текст.

Comment: В логах modx должен быть указан модуль который вызвал ошибку посмотрите последние записи в файле /core/cache/logs/error.log

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Это то?:
[2019-11-01 13:42:23] (ERROR in modMenu::getSubMenus @ /home/i/infothek35/vmleasing/public_html/core/model/modx/modmenu.class.php : 145) modAction support is deprecated since version 2.3.0. Support for modAction has been replaced with routing based on a namespace and action name. Please update the extra with the namespace gallery to the routing based system.

Comment: Вот еще:
[2019-11-01 15:29:23] (ERROR in modMenu::getSubMenus @ /home/i/infothek35/vmleasing/public_html/core/model/modx/modmenu.class.php : 145) modAction support is deprecated since version 2.3.0. Support for modAction has been replaced with routing based on a namespace and action name. Please update the extra with the namespace gallery to the routing based system.

Comment: И вот:

Fri Nov 01 15:43:24 2019] [error] [client 84.244.18.108] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace

Comment: Нет, это не то. А вообще другие страницы открываются напрямую, к примеру через админку и правой кнопкой - просмотреть? А так начинайте разбираться с дополнениями или сниппетами скорее всего, отключайте их по одному, ищите какое рушит систему. Может есть что-то связанное с сортировкой по названию страницы `pagetitle` или ограничением в 20 записей (это исходя из ошибки запроса)